# ItextSharp, Save Pdf Without Displaying Open / Save Dialog Box

Tags: asp.net, pdf, itext

Is it possible not to show Open/Save dialog? I would like to save the pdf file straight to specific disk location on client PC.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you are just use `jpeg`.

Comment: Unless you have absolute control over both the client and the server then no, this would be a giant security risk. By "absolute control" I mean you (the server) knows who the client is and how their disk(s) are arranged (not everyone has a `C:`), the client has remote file sharing turned on in a protocol that the server supports (SMB/AFP/etc) and the server has file system permissions to write to the client. There's also dozens of other things that can break but I'm keeping it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write the file directly to disk without the use of a save dialog.  All you need is a directory path to write too.

```
string path = "C:\YourDirectoryPathHere";

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(path, "NameYourFile.pdf"), myPDF);
```

This assumes myPDF is a `byte[]`.